# Function that calculates the percentage in a list

Tags: python

I need to make a function that calculates the lower percentage to a value within a list. For example, there a 70.5% lower than val elements in the list. The code incomplete:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 10]
p = [(i, Counter(l)[i] / float(len(l)) * 100.0) for i in Counter(l)]
l.sort()
newList = l[int(len(l) * .70)]

print newList, p
```

I have a 70%, but I need make this in function with value, I'm using python 2.7

Comment: can you please clarify your question. What is the variable that needs to be changed here?

Comment: _"there a 70.5% lower than val elements in the list"_ - I don't get you. Could you explain a bit more? I am assuming 'val' is a variable, but I don't see defined anywhere.

Comment: I need to make a function that works with all written code. For example def percentage (value): all code written and printed. I think that would fail me only that

Comment: your still not answering the question, we know what a function does.. What is the vriable that would be changed in your function? Is it the percentage value, it it the list(l)? what needs to change with each function call?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the percentage of items in a list that are less than an input, you could sort the list, get the number of items before the first occurrence of the number, divide it by the total number of items and multiply it by 100. Like so:

```
list = [23, 22, 3, 4, 5, 11, 23, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
sorted_li = sorted(li)
val = int(input())
len(sorted_li[:sorted_li.index(val)]) / float(len(sorted_li)) * 100
```